# Codeigniter: why the results of data parsing in controller and different model

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I tried sending a ID using checkbox with JavaScript. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function searchFilter() {
var colours = document.getElementsByName('colour[]');
var colour = "";
for (var i=0, n=colours.length;i<n; i++) 
    {
        if (colours[i].checked) 
    {
        colour += ","+colours[i].value;
    }
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Cataloguegaes/ajaxData/',
    data:'colour='+colour,
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (html) {
        $('#postList').html(html);
    }
});
}
```

And my html:

```
<label><b>colour :</b></label>
<ul class="list-unstyled rat">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="colour" name="colour[]" onclick="searchFilter();" value="1"><span>black</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="colour" name="colour[]" onclick="searchFilter();" value="2"><span>white</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="colour" name="colour[]" onclick="searchFilter();" value="3"><span>blue</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Black color is worth 1 when I send to controller e.g. black color. The result of the ID is correct `print_r ($id) // **,1*`*

This my controller Cataloguegaes:

```
function ajaxData(){
    $conditions = array();
    $colour     = $this->input->post('colour');

    print_r($colour); // result is 1 eg black

    if(!empty($colour)){
        $conditions['search']['colour'] = $colour;
    }

    //total rows count
    $totalRec = count($this->catalok->get_all_product($conditions));

     //get posts data
    $data['posts'] = $this->catalok->get_all_produk($conditions);

    //load the view
    $this->load->view('view_filtering',$data);
}
```

But as I proceed to the model the result turns to // **,1,1,1**

And my model Catalok:

```
function get_all_product($params = array()){
    $this->db->select('a.*, b.*');
    $this->db->from('product a');
    $this->db->join('product_get_color b','b.id_product =a.id_product','left');
    $this->db->where('a.status','on');
    $this->db->group_by('a.id_product');

    // sort data by colour
    print_r($params['search']['colour']); // this result **,1,1 IN HERE MY PROBLEM, Should be, 1**
    if(!empty($params['search']['colour'])){
    $this->db->where_in('c.id_opsi_get_colour',$params['search']['colour']);
    }elseif($params['search']['colour'] = 0){

    }
    //get records
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //return fetched data
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
}
```

OK. i make simple my code. and And I have written the line of code that became my problem.

My goal is to select the product color with checkbox.
Please tell me how I can handle my problem. Thank you from Indonesian people!

Comment: I gave it a try, using your code imported into CodeIgniter, but there is too much extra code. You're going to need to simplify the code to find the problem.

Comment: ok. i make simple code

Comment: Ok. I have my simple coding

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. If `$colour = 1` then that means `$conditions['search']['colour'] = 1`, and when you pass that to your method, there is no manipulation, which means that it should still = 1. In CodeIgniter on my server it = 1. I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: I have found my problem. It is due to repetition of 2 same models. Between **row count** and **get post to view**. I need a row count to calculate pagination data whereas in get post I need to send result to view. How to avoid duplicate variables? Can you simplify my code?

Comment: No, that is part of learning the job. You'll have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

just adding explode. hehe

```
$this->db->where_in('c.id_opsi_get_color',explode(',', $params['search']['colour']));
```